# reloadSections UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to reload section and update the number of cells in a section, but I'm getting an error and crash whenever I try. Here is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit
import CalendarView
import SwiftMoment

class TimeAwayRequestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var calendarView: CalendarView!

var selectedDates : [Moment] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calendarView.delegate = self
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnInt = 0

    if section == 0 {
        returnInt = 2
    }
    if section == 1 {
        returnInt = 1
    }

    if section == 2 {
        print(selectedDates.count)
       returnInt = selectedDates.count
    }

    return returnInt
}

}

extension TimeAwayRequestTableViewController : CalendarViewDelegate {

func calendarDidSelectDate(date: Moment) {
    selectedDates.append(date)
    print(selectedDates)
    let section = NSIndexSet(index: 2)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadSections(section, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

func calendarDidPageToDate(date: Moment) {
    print(date)
}

}
```

So basically when the date is tapped in the calendar, I add it to the Array and then update the number of cells. I haven't gotten to the point where I configure the cell content, right now I'm just trying to make sure this is working like i want. The error I get is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

But i don't understand why because it counts and shows 2. So I'm confused.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to reload _section_ 2 not row 2. Try `NSIndexSet(index: 0)`

Comment: Add a [exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) so that we can see where is `NSRangeException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you used some arrays(including `selectedDates`) in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` and it was beyond of bounds.Please check your data.

Comment: I do not have cellForRowAtIndexPath currently set up.

Comment: @trever so how your code is compile even? where does it go after `numberOfRowsInSection ` to setup the cells?

Comment: @trever Did you use static table view? How could you not set up this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing this right, i want to mix a static tableview cell and dynamic cells, think of it like the Wi-Fi section in iOS.

Comment: @trever you can't do that.

Comment: So is there any recommendation on how i should do it?

Comment: @trever If you want to do that,add dynamic table view to static one's tableFooterView/tableHeaderView as you can only use static table view in UITableViewController.

Comment: I should add another tableview inside of the static tableview?

Comment: @trever Yes,you got it!